# Write a Python function histogram(l) that takes as input a list of integers with repetitions and returns a list of pairs

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python function histogram(l) that takes as input a list of integers with repetitions and returns a list of pairs as follows:
for each number n that appears in l, there should be exactly one pair (n,r) in the list returned by the function, where r is is the number of repetitions of n in l.

the final list should be sorted in ascending order by r, the number of repetitions. For numbers that occur with the same number of repetitions, arrange the pairs in ascending order of the value of the number.

For instance:

> > > histogram([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12])
> > >       [(11, 1), (7, 2), (12, 2), (14, 2), (13, 4)]
> > >
> > > histogram([7,12,11,13,7,11,13,14,12])
> > >       [(14, 1), (7, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2)]

Comment: This is not a code-for-free site. Show us what your current code is, what you have come up with so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: i dont no how to write it in python .  thats why i have posted question

Comment: Than either you shouldn't take the assignment (that's what it looks like) or you should start [learning python](https://www.learnpython.org/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems), and a detailed description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Does not work, please help me are not acceptable

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def histogram(L):
...     from collections import Counter
...     return Counter(L).items()
... 
>>> histogram([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12])
[(11, 1), (12, 2), (13, 4), (14, 2), (7, 2)]
>>> histogram([7,12,11,13,7,11,13,14,12])
[(11, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2), (14, 1), (7, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def histogram(l):
b=[]
x=[]
f=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    a=()
    if l[i] not in x:
        c=l.count(l[i])
        f.append(c)
        f.sort()
        a=a+(l[i],c)
        b.append(a)
        x.append(l[i])
        del a
    else:
        continue
b=sorted(b,key=lambda f: (f[1],f[0]))
return b
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aashutosh singh for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have any questions about my code, feel free to ask. 
And if my code needs any improvements, please tell me.

```
def histogram(l):
    count = 0
    x=[]
    k=[]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        index=i
        count=0
        for j in range(index,len(l)):
            if l[index] == l[j] and l[index] not in k :
                count =count + 1
        k = k + [l[index]] 
        if (count != 0): 
            x = x + [(l[index], count)]
    x.sort()
    x=sorted(x,key=lambda x:x[1])

return x


#print(histogram([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12]))
```

Comment: While this might be an answer to this question, it is encouraged to add some explanation. SO is also not Code Review to discuss code improvements. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
def histogram(l):
    a=[]
    ans=[]
    for n in l:
       if n not in a:
          r=l.count(n)
          a.append(n)
          y=(n,r)
          ans.append(y)
        ans.sort()
        ans.sort(key=lambda r :r[1])
     return ans
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @NKSM’s point is always good advice, but it’s _especially_ important here where there are three existing answers. What distinguishes your approach? Under what conditions might your approach be preferred?